# How to make a histogram the shows the number of 0s, 1s, and NAs

Tags: r

I have a column in a dataset that contains only either 0s, 1s, or `NA`s. How can I make a histogram to show the count of each one of them? Basically having three bars on the x-axis, which would be 0, 1, and `NA`. The y-axis would be the count of each.

Comment: I like @jpsmith's answer, but keep in mind that you can always choose to do something like  `foo[is.na(foo)] <-  2`  and then do a bar plot or histogram (pick the 'breaks' carefully!'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, try using `barplot` with `useNA = "aways"` (or `"ifany"`, if desired):

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- sample(c(1,0,NA), 100, replace = TRUE)

barplot(table(dat, useNA = "always"), names.arg = c("1", "0", "NA"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(vals = sample(c(NA_real_,0,1),size = 100,replace = T)) %>%
  mutate(vals = factor(vals))


ggplot(df,aes(x=vals))+
  geom_bar()
```

Comment: You should use `geom_bar()` rather than `geom_histogram(stat = "count")`. Histograms are for continuous variables where you don't expect one value to repeat more than once so data must be binned.